# Root finding in R using pracma fzero function

Tags: r

I am working with this code to find the roots of the equation using pracma fzero function.

```
library(doParallel)
library(pracma)

n <- 2

root <- function(x) {
   return(x**2+5*x+6)
}

result1 = foreach(i=1:n) %do% fzero(root,i) #Normal for loop

print("Normal Loop completed.")

myCluster <- makeCluster(4, type = "PSOCK") 
registerDoParallel(myCluster)

result2 = foreach(i=1:n) %dopar% fzero(root,i) #Parallel for loop

print("Parallel Loop completed.")

stopCluster(myCluster)
```

I get the output using normal for loop. But when using the parallel for loop, I get this error.

```
Error in fzero(root, i): task 1 failed - "could not find function "fzero""
Traceback:

1. foreach(i = 1:n) %dopar% fzero(root, i)
2. e$fun(obj, substitute(ex), parent.frame(), e$data)
```

I don't know how to solve this error.

Comment: I didn't discern why, but if you add the package name, you will not get an error: 
`foreach(i = 1:n, %dopar% pracma::fzero(root, i)`. I would rather know the why of it, but at least this works in the meantime. On a side note, you could also use `parallel::mclapply(1:n, function(x) fzero(root, x))`. The results are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a PSOCK cluster, it starts up independent R processes using Rscript, so you need to tell them to load the requisite packages. Explicitly naming the package like `pracma::fzero` works or [foreach](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/foreach/html/foreach.html) has an argument `.packages`:

> .packages
> character vector of packages that the tasks depend on. If ex requires a R package to be loaded, this option can be used to load that package on each of the workers. Ignored when used with %do%.

If you use `foreach(i=1:n, .packages = c("pracma"))` it works as well.